# Is it okay to make static method async?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, coreclr, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a utility class in `ASP.NET Core 2` that sends notification using AWS simple notification service. Since this is utility class i made it static, and `AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient's` publish method is async i made my wrapping static method also async

```
public static class AwsHelper
{
    public static async Task SendNotification(string topicArn, string sub, string message)
    {
        var arn = ParseArn(topicArn);
        using (var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(arn.Region))
        {
            await client.PublishAsync(new PublishRequest
            {
                Subject = sub,
                Message = message,
                TopicArn = topicArn
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the code, and it worked fine.

However is it okay to make static method async?

Comment: Being `static` doesn't change anything

Comment: I'd say that `static` and `async` are not correlated in anyway.

Comment: the reason i asked, if i remember correctly ( and i could be wrong) in VS 2011 `async static` was not allowed

Comment: @LP13 If that was so, you can't have asynchronous utility operations, which is strange, right?